# How to deal with dynamic text size on iPhones

Tags: swiftui

so I'm building my first app using SwiftUI, and now I'm dealing with the situation where a user can change the text size on his phone dynamically.

Right now I have a sheet that's just a VStack with a bunch of Text, using different font sizes, such as:

```
VStack {
  Text(...).font(.title)
  Text(...).font(.headline)
  Text(...).font(.body)
  ...
}
```

And it all fits fine on the default text size. However, if the user chooses a larger text size (Settings->Display & Brightness -> Text Size), then it all doesn't fit as lines begin to wrap.

The easy answer is to add a ScrollView around everything, but I really want everything to be visible (no scrolling), no matter what Text size is chosen by the user (ie, scale the font sizes accordingly), or something like:

```
VStack {
  Text(...)
  Text(...)
  ....
}.shrinkFontsToFit()
```

What's a "best practice" to accomplish something like this?

Thx.

Comment: You should not counteract the will of the user without a very good reason, and this doesn't qualify. Therefore, you need to be prepared to handle larger text sizes. Put it in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Yrb Well, I don't think it's that simple. This is part of a game, and as the designer, I'm deciding that the user experience is much better if everything is displayed w/o scrolling, at the cost of smaller fonts, ie, I think it's a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: So basically you DONT want the user to change the size? Just specify fixed font sizes then.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the notion of @ScaledMetric. This allows me to have a dynamic size based on the user's preference, and it allows me to essentially choose my own set of "canned" font sizes instead of relying on the defaults (so I can make them fit in some particular View).

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @ScaledMetric var myLargeTitleSize: CGFloat = 20.0
    @ScaledMetric var myTitleSize: CGFloat = 17.0
    @ScaledMetric var myBodySize: CGFloat = 11.0

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            Text(..).font(.system(size: myLargeTitleSize))
            Text(..).font(.system(size: myTitleSize))
            Text(..).font(.system(size: myBodySize))
        }
   }
}
```